# request.getAttribute returns null in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm basically setting attribute in Servlet and trying to get it into jsp but it keeps returning null. Any idea why?

Servlet :

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        combobox=request.getParameter("selectedid");
        Test t=new Test();
        String content=t.giveSelected(combobox);
        request.setAttribute("contentData", content);
        response.sendRedirect("/WebTest-iFrame/iFrame.jsp");
    }
```

JSP:

```
    <%
     String content=(String)request.getAttribute("contentData");
    %>
    <script>
        function iFramefunc(){
            var s = document.getElementById('iframe');
            s.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML="<%=content%>";
            s.contentDocument.close();
        }
    </script>
    <iframe id="iframe" onload="iFramefunc()"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **response.sendRedirect("/WebTest-iFrame/iFrame.jsp");**, try using **RequestDispatcher** because **sendRedirect** will create a new request object in which there will be no attributes, therefore you are getting null as a result.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WebTest-iFrame/iFrame.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This will forward same request and response object to the requested URL.

Comment: It returns 404, so dispatcher should also redirect the page into jsp?

Comment: Yup, try removing first / from the path.